# Is it possible to replicate shiny element across application

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I'm working on a simple Shiny application that consists of multiple panels, with the the `ui.R` structured similarly to the code below:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Example",
                   tabPanel("Sample analysis",
                            sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                    sliderInput("bins",
                                                "Number of bins:",
                                                min = 1,
                                                max = 50,
                                                value = 30)
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                    plotOutput("distPlot")
                                )
                            )),
                   tabPanel("Sample analysis 2",
                            sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                    sliderInput("bins",
                                                "Number of bins (again!)",
                                                min = 1,
                                                max = 50,
                                                value = 30)
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                    plotOutput("distPlot")
                                )
                            ))
))
```

Each of the panel provides access to different functionalities but certain aspects of the code are the same. For example each of the panels may provide access to a some selection mechanism for one particular object, in the case of the example above illustrated as `sliderInput` replicated across two panels. I'm interested in exploring *whether it would be possible to replicate the same part of the interface `x` number of times without the need to type the whole `sliderInput` code?*

---

#### Edit

To complicate the problem further, within my function I would like to have a reactive component, on the lines:

```
build_eqls_drop_down <- function(){
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("selection", h5("Selection"), dynamic_vars()),
                 uiOutput("dynamic_list_derived_according_to_selection"))
}
```

when encapsulated in the function the `uiOutput`-generated element does not appear. In addition, I would be happy for the function to take no parameters as I don't mind `ui` elements having the same id (in effect I'm trying to have one element in different places).

Comment: you can just have a variable `slider <- sliderInput...`  holding the object at the start of your `ui.R` and just replace your slier blocks by that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to create a function with the elements you want to replicate. Later just call the function. You can define your default parameters there, but always try to have a different `inputId` on each element to avoid conflicts.

Here is a sample code that use a function to create an slider with default parameters. Please note in the second tabpanel that you can replicate `x` number of times the slider using `lapply` (in this example 3 times). Also note that you can change your default parameters.

```
library(shiny)

build_slider <- function(id, label="Number of bins:", mxmi=c(1,50), val=30){
    sliderInput(id,
                    label,
                    min = mxmi[1],
                    max = mxmi[2],
                    value = val)
}

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(navbarPage("Example",
        tabPanel("Sample analysis",
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    build_slider("bins_1")
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("distPlot_1")
                )
        )),
        tabPanel("Sample analysis 2",
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    lapply(1:3, function(k) { 
                        id = paste("bins", k, sep="_")
                        build_slider(id, val = k*10)
                    })
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("distPlot_2")
                )
        ))
    )),

    server = function(input, output, session) { }
))
```

You can create a function to create shiny elements as complex as you want. So you can create a function to create a complete `tapPanel` that includes any number of widgets and plots.